# Setting button focus in a graphcisview

Tags: qt, button, qt4, qgraphicsview

I have placed a few buttons in a `Qgraphicsscene`, but I don’t know how to navigate to the button from a keyboard.

How would I set the focus to a button from the keyboard?

Comment: Could you write some code snippet to get some notion what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you used [`QGraphicsScene::addWidget()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) to add the button to the scene? It gives you a proxy object back, [`QGraphicsProxyWidget *`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsproxywidget.html), which inherits  [`QGraphicsItem::setFocus()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#setFocus). But remember that it needs to have set the [`ItemIsFocusable`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag and needs to be visible and active as well.

Additionally (from the setFocus() documentation):

> As a result of calling this function, this item will receive a focus in event with focusReason. If another item already has focus, that item will first receive a focus out event indicating that it has lost input focus.

Comment: Haha. Didn't even notice that the question was a year old. :p